# probability chances

Tags: probability

A lottery draw consist of 38 numbers. Marty always plays numbers 1 thru 12. What is the probability that her 8th attempt at playing the lottery will result in her 3rd win.

So we have P(winning)= 12/38 and P(lose) = 26/38
Confused to rather this problem should be worked as

[(26/38)^7 (12/38)]/ (26/38)^7 =.3158    or

(26/38)^7 (12/38) = .0222  or

(26/38)^7 (12/38)^3 = .0047

I guess I am not totally understanding the malnipulation of ensuring the 3rd bets placement.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  She has to win any two of the first seven tries, then win the eighth.

Comment: Yes, that is obvious... but what defines the actual placement of the win... or does the solution merely have to denote the quantification of having 3 wins within 8 tries??

Comment: You need to account for the number of ways of choosing which two of the first seven are wins.  None of your examples have that.  You also need to account for the proper number of wins and loses.  Again, none of your examples account for that.  What is the probability she wins two out of the first seven?  That is a standard binomial calculation.